# Автопрокрутка ScrollViewer в C# UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Имеется кусок кода

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5 5 5 5" BorderBrush="Brown" Background="#FFE6F3FF">
                    <ScrollViewer Name="ConsoleScrollPanel" VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
                        <StackPanel Name="Console"  Margin="10,0,10,0" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

В StackPanel  постепенно будут добавляться элементы TextBlock. Как сделать, чтобы при их добавлении ScrollViewer автоматически скролил панель вверх? чтобы были видны новые присоединившиеся снизу текстовые блоки.

Comment: Посмотрите для начала какие есть методы у ScrollViewer. Может найдете нужный самостоятельно

Comment: пробовал добавить это, но всеровно не получается

`
var transform = printTextBlock.TransformToVisual((UIElement)ConsoleScrollPanel.Content);
  var position = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
  ConsoleScrollPanel.ChangeView(null, position.Y, null, true);
`